# Large variations in capacitor cost

Tags: capacitor, cost

I am very surprised with difference in capacitor cost (up to 10 times) like [this](https://www.digikey.in/product-detail/en/knowles-syfer/2220Y6300105KXTWS2/1608-2220Y6300105KXTWS2CT-ND/5730380) and [this](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Multilayer-Ceramic-Capacitors-MLCC-SMD-SMT_PSA-Prosperity-Dielectrics-FS55X105K631EHG_C784102.html).
These two have same capacitance along with voltage rating and tolerance level.Then what are the reasons behind these high differences in cost ,is it something due to material used to design it or it is just due to the different vendor providing it ?

Comment: Which one do you trust the most?

Comment: https://www.digikey.in/

Comment: Are you prepared to pay 10 times more to get that peace of mind?

Comment: obviously not :(  I will avoid to use it

Comment: Or I will use through hole package rather then paying 10 times more

Comment: If i am making my own personal project, then I’d go for the cheaper item. If I was making 1000 pcbs with the part, i’d be looking at the more expensive part. As for the difference in cost, DK aren’t known as a budget supplier and you pay for the convenience and the promise that the parts are from known sources. I’ve been bitten too many times by counterfeit and poor quality components. The cost of repair can far outstrip the savings of a few cents.